# An inequality between two real-valued concave functions

Tags: real-analysis

Can anyone help me prove the following inequality? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: This question is useful to solve an economic model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Professor Mohamed,

$g(x)=T(\delta x)$

$k_{1}=f'^{-1}(g'(0))$

$f-g$  is increasing in the interval $[0,\hat{k}]$,
$k_{1}$ belongs to this interval, so we have $(f-g)(\hat{k})>(f-g)(k_{1})$

remains to show that in $[0,k_{1}]$, the tangent in 0 of g is between the 2 curves :
this tangent is above $ g$, because $g$ is concave,
it is below $f$ because its coefficient is $f '(k_ {1})$ and it's $<f' (x)  \forall  x$   in $[0,k_{1}]$, because $f$ is concave